# Problems with parsing JSON for D3

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, flask

I am building an app with Flask and Python, and I want to pass some of my Python-generated results into JSON, so that they can be visualized with D3 under a container fluid. To do this, I am trying to use the Jinja method `var myjson = {{jsonDict|tojson }};`. Here `jsonDict` is a variable in my Python code that is a string of a dict, where single quotes have been replaced with double quotes with a regular expression, so that it looks like proper JSON. I am also using the JS method `root = JSON.parse( myjson );`. I believe that the combination of these two should solve my problem, but when I run the code, however I am getting the error:

```
(index):2222    
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token y in JSON at position 0 
uo  @   d3.v3.min.js:3
i   @   d3.v3.min.js:1
```

Here is the D3 template that I am trying to use:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

Here is my implementation of this D3 (just the relevant script):

```
<script>

var margin = 20,
    diameter = 960;

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .padding(2)
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })

var svg = d3.select("#dan").append("svg") //#dan is name of my container fluid
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

//this is the part of the code I have added //
var myjson = {{ jsonDict|tojson }};
root = JSON.parse( myjson );
//this is the part of the code I have added //    

d3.json("root", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error; //this is index 2222

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack.nodes(root),
      view;

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

  d3.select("#dan")
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .each("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .each("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

As you can see, I replaced the original JS lines from the D3 code:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

with:

```
var myjson = {{ jsonDict|tojson }};
    root = JSON.parse( myjson );   

    d3.json("root", function(error, root) {
```

As I have my code now, if I inspect the page, the `svg` shows up on the webpage in the correct place, but it is blank.

I am new to D3 and Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT - console logs

if I do console.log(myjson), the console prints the string of the JSON properly (see below)

if I do console.log(root), the console prints

```
Object {children: Array[2], name: "flare"}
children:Array[2]
name:"flare"
__proto__:Object
__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__:__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__:__lookupSetter__()
constructor:Object()
hasOwnProperty:hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf:isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable:propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString:toLocaleString()
toString:toString()
valueOf:valueOf()
get __proto__:__proto__()
set __proto__:__proto__()
```

So it seems that the `JSON.parse` method is failing me somehow.

EDIT -- my JSON string that is being passed from Python into `var myjson`

```
{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name": "concept0", "children": [{"name": "intermediate host", "size": 700}, {"name": "abstrusus brevior", "size": 700}, {"name": "stage larva", "size": 700}, {"name": "anterior extremity", "size": 700}, {"name": "crenosoma vulpi", "size": 700}]}, {"name": "concept1", "children": [{"name": "infected cat", "size": 700}, {"name": "abstrusus infection", "size": 700}, {"name": "domestic cat", "size": 700}, {"name": "feline aelurostrongylosis", "size": 700}, {"name": "cat infect", "size": 700}]}]}
```

pagesource for `console.log(myjson)`

```
{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name": "concept0", "children": [{"size": 700, "name": "intermediate host"}, {"size": 700, "name": "abstrusus brevior"}, {"size": 700, "name": "stage larva"}, {"size": 700, "name": "anterior extremity"}, {"size": 700, "name": "crenosoma vulpi"}]}, {"name": "concept1", "children": [{"size": 700, "name": "infected cat"}, {"size": 700, "name": "abstrusus infection"}, {"size": 700, "name": "domestic cat"}, {"size": 700, "name": "feline aelurostrongylosis"}, {"size": 700, "name": "cat infect"}]}]}
```

EDIT - I think the problem can be seen in `console.log(root)`. I've checked other D3 visualizations and the log should typically look like this:

```
Object {name: "flare", children: Array[5]}
children: Array[5]
depth:0
name:"flare"
r:470
value:21000
x:470
y:470
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: use console.log(root) to see what root is in the developer console of whatever browser you're using. Verify you root is proper JSON, and in the right format D3 is expecting.

Comment: console.log(root) shows up as an "Object", but console.log(myjson) prints out the JSON string properly (but doesn't define it as an object or anything). I've used JSON.parse before on this same data (but different D3 code) and it worked fine. I guess I need a different method to make it read as JSON? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you share the JSON string? It looks like the format may not be valid.

Comment: @Owen I have added it at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: @SnarkShark Thanks - and is that exactly how it's listed in the page source? Would you mind copying the output line beginning `var myjson =` ?

Comment: @Owen, sorry I didn't see this sooner! Yup, `var myjson` is listed in the page source exactly the same as my JSON string. I'll add it to my post as well.

Comment: You are using `tojson()` in your jinja template. **This function converts the given object into JSON representation.** so why do you need to use `JSON.parse()` afterwards? Can you not just pass in `myjson`?

Comment: @Craicerjack, I just tested it and you are correct that  `JSON.parse()` makes no difference in my code. Without it, (and re-naming the `tojson()` object "root" instead of "myjson"), I still get the console error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token y in JSON at position 2222" and the D3 visualization does not show up. (Position 2222 is the `if (error) throw error`)

Comment: Looking at your code again and you have `d3.json("root", function(error, root) {` this is passing in the string `"root"` to the `d3.json` method and not the variable `root`. You should remove the double quotes from this

Comment: The `d3.json` takes a url as its parameter, its an ajax request in essence, but you already have your data there so dont need to call this. Try running your code without the `d3.json()` function

Comment: @Craicerjack When I removed the `d3.json()` function it worked as it should! Thank you! I would like to better understand WHY I cannot use the function here. Is it because I only need the function if I have a url because of ajax?  Thanks again! :D

Comment: @Craicerjack, if you'd like, you can copy/paste your response about the `d3.json()` function as a answer to my question, that way I can accept it as the best answer and you'll get credit for answering a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are already passing your json to your client via your flask application there is no need to use d3's `d3.json()` method. `d3.json()` is essentially an `ajax` `GET` request which requests the file from the server.

> ## d3.json(url[, callback])
>
> Creates a request for the JSON file at the specified url with the mime
>   type "application/json". If a callback is specified, the request is
>   immediately issued with the GET method, and the callback will be
>   invoked asynchronously when the file is loaded or the request fails;
>   the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the
>   parsed JSON. The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs. If no
>   callback is specified, the returned request can be issued using
>   xhr.get or similar, and handled using xhr.on.

You already had your data stored in a variable on in your javascript so there was no need to request it from the server.
Also when you tried to request it you were passing in an invalid url.
Removing the `d3.json()` function and just running the rest of the code should work.